# Find size of multiple databases in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, size

I was wondering if there is a sql statement to get the current size of all the databases on your server instead of right clicking and going to properties for each one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use stored procedures, this should work:

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'use ? exec sp_spaceused'
```

Comment: Although this will give back a resultset for each of the databases which looks a bit messy. I prefer to use my answer which gives a *nice* table.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [sys.master_files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx) table.

This query will give you total size of everything in your instance:

```
SELECT SUM(size*8192.0) AS totalsize
FROM sys.master_files;
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use:

```
exec [sys].[sp_databases]
go
```

Which produces something like:

```
Name        Size  Remarks
mydatabase1 29888 NULL
mydatabase2 13760 NULL
mydatabase3 11776 NULL
master      5376  NULL
model       3008  NULL
msdb        7616  NULL
tempdb      2560  NULL
```

For the size of the transaction logs associated with a database, use:

```
dbcc sqlperf(logspace)
go
```

Which produces something like:

```
Name        Log Size (MB) Log Space Used (%) Status
master      1.242188      50.9434            0
tempdb      0.7421875     61.25              0
model       0.7421875     38.94737           0
msdb        1.992188      35.88235           0
mydatabase1 5.554688      18.55661           0
mydatabase2 2.742188      32.9594            0
mydatabase3 8.992188      26.58015           0
```

Comment: hey thomas, is there a way to format the ouput of the first query in MB directly? thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
exec sp_helpdb
```

Lists out the size of data, owner, creation date, etc for all databases on a server in one nice table.

If you then want to go delving into a particular database to see the individual table sizes you can use

```
use MyFunkyDb
go
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable 'EXECUTE sp_spaceused [?]'
```